# Make returned Future Send if parameters are Send

Tags: rust, async-await, traits, rust-futures

Can I propagate the `Send` trait of function parameters to its return type, so that the return type is `impl Send` if and only if the parameters are?

**Details:**

An async function has a nice feature. Its returned `Future` is automatically `Send` if it can be. In the following example, the async function will create a `Future` that is `Send`, if the inputs to the function are `Send`.

```rust
struct MyStruct;

impl MyStruct {
    // This async fn returns an `impl Future<Output=T> + Send` if `T` is Send.
    // Otherwise, it returns an `impl Future<Output=T>` without `Send`.
    async fn func<T>(&self, t: T) -> T {
        t
    }
}

fn assert_is_send(_v: impl Send) {}

fn main() {
    // This works
    assert_is_send(MyStruct.func(4u64));
    // And the following correctly fails
    assert_is_send(MyStruct.func(std::rc::Rc::new(4u64)));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5475632a87a04db3ccb9f1ddba42b28b)

Now, I want to move such a function into a trait, which requires using async-trait (which is some codegen that effectively writes my `async fn` as a function returning `Pin<Box<dyn Future>>`) or doing something similar manually. Is there a way to write this in a way to retain this auto-Send behavior where the returned `Future` is made `Send` if `T` is `Send`? The following example implements it as two separate functions:

```rust
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::future::Future;

struct MyStruct;
impl MyStruct {
    fn func_send<T: 'static + Send>(&self, t: T) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = T> + Send>> {
        Box::pin(async{t})
    }
    
    fn func_not_send<T: 'static>(&self, t: T) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = T>>> {
        Box::pin(async{t})
    }
}

fn assert_is_send(_v: impl Send) {}

fn main() {
    // This works
    assert_is_send(MyStruct.func_send(4u64));
    // And the following correctly fails
    // assert_is_send(MyStruct.func(std::rc::Rc::new(4u64)));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=65f5400d7bb204e9da6292ccc5276995)

But actually, I don't want them to be separate. I want them to be one function similar to how `async fn` does it automatically. Something along the lines of

```rust
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::future::Future;

struct MyStruct;
impl MyStruct {
    fn func<T: 'static + ?Send>(&self, t: T) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = T> + ?Send>> {
        Box::pin(async{t})
    }
}

fn assert_is_send(_v: impl Send) {}

fn main() {
    // This should
    assert_is_send(MyStruct.func(4u64));
    // And this should fail
    assert_is_send(MyStruct.func(std::rc::Rc::new(4u64)));
}
```

Is something like this possible in Rust? I'm ok with writing the async-trait magic manually and modifying it instead of using the async-trait crate if that is a way to make it work.

Some ideas I had but they haven't really borne fruit yet:

- Use min-specialization to specialize on `Send`? But doesn't seem like that feature is going to be stabilized anytime soon so maybe not the best option.
- Return a custom `MyFuture` type instead of just `impl Future` and somehow `impl Send for MyFuture where T: Send`? Would probably be difficult though since I would have to be able to name that `Future` and `async` code usually produces `impl Future` types that cannot be named.
- Writing a procedural macro that adds `+ Send` to the return type if it recognizes that the input type is `Send`. Actually, can procedural macros detect if a certain type implements `Send`? My guess would be it's not possible since they just work on token streams.

Comment: You could try #2 and store in your struct a `Pin<Box<dyn Future>` and use [pin projection](https://crates.io/crates/pin-project) to implement `Future` for it, but I don't think even this will be enough. For a `Future` to be `Send` it must not only return type that is `Send`, but it must not hold any non-send types across await points. May I ask what even are you trying to do? Why do you want this duality?

Comment: I'm writing a library that has a couple of common data types with a common API, so I want to put the API into a trait. The API has `async fn`s and those functions keep their parameters across `await` points, so they can be `Send` if and only if their parameters are. I want users to be able to move the futures generated by the API to different threads if they use the API with `Send` types but I also want to entirely forbid usage of non-`Send` types, so I need the duality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(2) is the only way that could work.

There are two ways to make it work:

1. Write the future manually, without the help of `async` and `.await`. But that means writing the future manually:

```rust
enum ConditionalSendFut<T> {
    Start { t: T },
    Done,
}

impl<T> Unpin for ConditionalSendFut<T> {}

impl<T> Future for ConditionalSendFut<T> {
    type Output = T;

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, _context: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        match &mut *self {
            Self::Start { .. } => {
                let t = match std::mem::replace(&mut *self, Self::Done) {
                    Self::Start { t } => t,
                    _ => unreachable!(),
                };
                Poll::Ready(t)
            }
            Self::Done => Poll::Pending,
        }
    }
}

struct MyStruct;
impl MyStruct {
    fn func<T: 'static>(&self, t: T) -> ConditionalSendFut<T> {
        ConditionalSendFut::Start { t }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5edf7ac83db51652474d15bb1b436305).

2. Store a `Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = T>>>` and conditionally impl `Send` on the future. But this requires `unsafe` code and manually ensuring that you don't hold other non-`Send` types across `.await` points:

```rust
struct ConditionalSendFut<T>(Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = T>>>);

// SAFETY: The only non-`Send` type we're holding across an `.await`
// point is `T`.
unsafe impl<T: Send> Send for ConditionalSendFut<T> {}

impl<T> Future for ConditionalSendFut<T> {
    type Output = T;

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, context: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        self.0.as_mut().poll(context)
    }
}

struct MyStruct;
impl MyStruct {
    fn func<T: 'static>(&self, t: T) -> ConditionalSendFut<T> {
        ConditionalSendFut(Box::pin(async { t }))
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=954c04ab308b2df8b470be8d626ba200).

(1) cannot work with traits, as each impl will have a different future. This leaves us with (2) only. I would not recommend it, but it is possible.

It is very likely that when async fns in traits will be stable there will be a mechanism to that (what is talked about currently is to impl them conditionally and use bounds on use sites to require them) but currently there is no such thing, even on the nightly implementation of async fns in traits.